# a tag hyperlinks not working on app engine

Tags: html, google-app-engine

I've currently got an odd problem. I have made a quick website and just want to navigate from one page to another. now locally everything works fine but when I place it on Google's App Engine my links just navigate to the index page. I'm not sure why though...

HTML:

```
<div style="width:90%;margin:auto;left:0;right:0;">
        <center>
            <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    Phase 1 <span class="caret"></span>
                  </button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="Phase1Before.html">Phase 1: Before Task</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Phase1After.html">Phase 1:  After Task</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="RemarksPhase1.html">Phase 1:  Remarks</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                  </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    Phase 2 <span class="caret"></span>
                  </button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="Phase2Before.html">Phase 2: Before Task</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Phase 2:After Task</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Phase 2:Remarks</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                  </ul>
            </div>
        </center>
    </div>
```

Folder Structure:

[image]

app.yaml:

```
application: appname-irm
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
  expiration: 30d

- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|ttf))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|ttf))

- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: static/favicon.ico
  upload: static/favicon.ico
  expiration: 30d

- url: .*
  script: index.html
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working on app engine

Comment: script: index.html - this would need to be a Python script. If you want to serve a static HTML file, configure it like your favicon. And by locally, do you mean using dev_appserver?

Comment: @Bugs I've added a new section in the yaml file just like the favicon section I'v just replaced favicon with index.html, still have the same problem though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my yaml file, simply just have a section for each page in the app:

```
application: myapp
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
  expiration: 30d

- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|ttf))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|ttf))

- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: static/favicon.ico
  upload: static/favicon.ico

- url: /phase1after.html
  static_files: phase1after.html
  upload: phase1after.html

- url: /phase1before.html
  static_files: phase1before.html
  upload: phase1before.html

- url: /phase2before.html
  static_files: phase2before.html
  upload: phase2before.html

- url: /remarksphase1.html
  static_files: remarksphase1.html
  upload: remarksphase1.html

- url: .*
  script: index.html
```

Comment: You may want to put all your static html files in a subdirectory so you can use one entry in your yaml with a wildcard rather than needing one per page.